# Abstract classes and move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

According to “Rule Of Five” when I declare one of: copy or move operation or destructor I must write all of them, because the compiler doesn't generate them (some of them) for me. But if my class (`A`) derives from an abstract class with a virtual destructor, does this mean that the destructor in class `A` will be considered "user-defined"? As a consequence, will move semantics not work with objects of this class `A` because compiler won't generate a move constructor for me?

```
struct Interface {
    virtual void myFunction() = 0;
    virtual ~Interface() {};
};

struct A : public Interface {
    void myFunction() override {};
};
```

Comment: An abstract class can't be instantiated.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @MikeMB I'm not working with any specific compiler.

Comment: if you need a virtual destructor, but you don't want to suppress anything, you can do that with `virtual ~T() = default;`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In [class.copy]:

> If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared
>   as defaulted if and only if
>   (9.1) — X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
>   (9.2) — X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
>   (9.3) — X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator, and
>   **(9.4) — X does not have a user-declared destructor.**
>   *[ Note:* When the move constructor is not implicitly declared or explicitly supplied, expressions that otherwise
>   would have invoked the move constructor may instead invoke a copy constructor. *—end note ]*

`Interface` does have a user-declared destructor, so `Interface`'s move constructor will not be implicitly declared as defaulted. But `A` doesn't fit any of those bullet points - so it **will** have an implicit move constructor that is defaulted. `A(A&& )`will just copy the `Interface` part, as per the note. We can verify this by adding members to `Interface` and `A`:

```
#include <iostream>

template <char c>
struct Obj {
    Obj() { std::cout << "default ctor" << c << "\n"; }  
    Obj(const Obj&) { std::cout << "copy ctor" << c << "\n"; }
    Obj(Obj&&) { std::cout << "move ctor" << c << "\n"; }
};

struct Interface {
    virtual void myFunction() = 0;
    virtual ~Interface() {};

    Obj<'I'> base;
};

struct A : public Interface {
    void myFunction() override {};

    Obj<'A'> derived;
};

int main() {
    A a1;                      // default I, default A
    std::cout << "---\n";
    A a2(std::move(a1));       // copy I, move A
    std::cout << "---\n";
    A a3(a2);                  // copy I, copy A
}
```

Comment: That `Interface` gets a defaulted copy constructor is a deprecated feature since C++11. It still exists in recent drafts, though.

Comment: @dyp "The latter case is deprecated if the class has
a user-declared copy assignment operator or a user-declared destructor." In what future revision will this be removed? C++17 maybe?

Comment: I don't know. [N3839](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3839.pdf) explores this, not sure what happened to it. -- Edit: [EWG #55 happened](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4327.html#55) I hope we get more warnings about it, soon (e.g. clang++ `-Wdeprecated`).